# pgfplots: Plot only parts of table and in "random" order

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have been lurking around stackexchange for a long time and so far been able to find solutions for my newbie problems but now I'm really stuck!
My problem is probably not that complicated, yet a bit hard to explain.

In my data file is a table with 4 columns. First column hold sample ID and the three remaining columns hold the y-data for 3 different stages. So far I have plotted Sample 13 to 17 as a line plot and I know how to do that:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{siunitx} % requires packages "l3packages" and "l3kernel"
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bottom = 0.50cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,spy,backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
SampleNo     Phase_1    Phase_2 Phase_3
13   10.72447   120.495518  280.505095
14  20.07597    170.114048  360.86694
15  -40.29807   120.443185  380.23223
16  -10.280941  160.268171  350.588343
17  10.591254   140.887412  310.085956
18  20.18464    190.566417  390.946054
19   10.63166   130.196773  270.610362
20  20.05172    180.115205  370.31739
21  10.71398    140.007552  290.080619
22   20.01196   170.877254  350.66182
23  20.21736    190.038692  380.31596
}\data

\begin{figure}[H]

%\centering
%\hspace{-1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=1cm, connect spies}]
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={line width=1pt},
    use units = true,
    xlabel = Sample No.,
    ylabel = Deformation,
   xmin=13,
   xmax=17,
    legend style={
       cells={anchor=west},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        %font=\scriptsize,
    },
    cycle list name=exotic,
    legend entries={
        Phase 1,Phase 2,Phase 3
        }
}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,cycle list name=exotic,]
    \addplot+[line join=bevel,line width=1pt,mark=none] table[y=Phase_1]{\data};
    \addplot+[line join=bevel,line width=1pt,mark=none] table[y=Phase_2]{\data};
    \addplot+[line join=bevel,line width=1pt,mark=none] table[y=Phase_3]{\data};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

Now to my problem:
I want to, preferbly in the same graph, plot a line plot also for Sample 13,24,23,22 and 21 (In that give order!)
They should span the same "x domain" as the first sample plotted and the ticks have to say "13/13" "14/24" and so on. That I guess could be solved more or less manually... My biggest issue is to get the mentioned sample in "my" order and located with no empty sample number inbetween.

Thanks in advance! I'll be more than happy to answer any further questions!

Comment: Side issue: Are you sure that a line plot is the most appropriate visualization for this dataset? Connecting the data points with a line implies that there is an inherent order, connection and continuity in the data, but I would assume that the samples are independent and discontinuous: they might as well be called "John", "Peter" and "Paul". What order would you put them in then? And there can't be a sample "14.5", yet from your plot I could predict the deformation value that sample would be expected to have. I think a scatter plot might be a better way to show the data.

Comment: I agree fully with you; however, in this case the samples represents deformations in equally spaced points located along lines 13-17 and (13,24,23,22,21). The deformation distribution between the points could be considered as linear... Anyway, thank you for your consideration!

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. Would it be possible (and perhaps even more useful) to not put the sample number on the x axis, but rather "Distance along transect" (or something along those lines)? That way, the data could be naturally ordered. Labelling each x coordinate using two different sample numbers would also make it impossible for the reader to know which line each sample number refers to: Maybe that information (if it is really necessary for the reader) would be better presented as labels along the line. (Obviously I'm trying to avoid answering your actual question of plotting values...

Comment: ... in a "random" order, because that's going to be pretty hard.)

Comment: I guess I have to do that! Problem is I would have liked to avoid it to keep my data assembling (made w. Python) more general purpose, but I can see no other solution. I think this will work out nice anyway! I'll keep checking this thread for possible additions in the upcoming days anyway! Thanks Jake for your response!!

Answer (score 1):

You can overlays multiple axes, only there are a lot of things to be set manually.

The trick is that, using `symbolic x coords`, one is able to arrange data points in the most direct way. Together with `xmin` and `xmax` one can filter out data points (in the most direct way).

Notice that this trick works only if your data points are "discontinuous". For continuous data, one might consider the `x coord trafo` family.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    SampleNo Phase_1   Phase_2     Phase_3
    13       10.72447  120.495518  280.505095
    14       20.07597  170.114048  360.86694
    15      -40.29807  120.443185  380.23223
    16      -10.280941 160.268171  350.588343
    17       10.591254 140.887412  310.085956
    18       20.18464  190.566417  390.946054
    19       10.63166  130.196773  270.610362
    20       20.05172  180.115205  370.31739
    21       10.71398  140.007552  290.080619
    22       20.01196  170.877254  350.66182
    23       20.21736  190.038692  380.31596
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
    my axis/.style={ymin=-100,ymax=400,axis lines=#1,only marks,enlarge x limits}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23},xmin=13,xmax=17,my axis=none]
        \addplot table[y=Phase_1]{\data};
        \addplot table[y=Phase_2]{\data};
        \addplot table[y=Phase_3]{\data};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={13,20,23,22,21,14,15,16,17,18,19},xmin=13,xmax=21,my axis=none]
        \addplot table[y=Phase_1]{\data};
        \addplot table[y=Phase_2]{\data};
        \addplot table[y=Phase_3]{\data};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={13,20,23,22,21,14,15,16,17,18,19},xmin=13,xmax=21,my axis=box,xticklabels={x,13/13,14/20,15/23,16/22,17/21}]
        \addplot coordinates{};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```